# How to say financial trader in Mandarin?

Tags: translation, mandarin

How does one say "trader" in Mandarin. I am meaning a financial trader who invests in the stock market. Would it be 股民？

谢谢

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Stock trader' as a job title is '股票交易员' They buy and sell stocks in the stock market for clients for short-term returns or long term investment

股民 (stockholder) refers to people who trade stocks themselves or through their agents on a part-time basis. There are stockholders who hold stocks for long term investment and they are called 股票投资者 (stock investors). There are stockholders who speculate the stock market like a gambler, and they are called 股票炒家 (stock speculators)

A financial consultant is a 财务顾问

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!